# The truth value of a series is ambiguous. Beginner Issues

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror

For a pandas dataframe with several columns I need to filter certain values and return a value in another column.

For example:

```
df = { "Strings" : ["string_a", "string_b", "string_b", "string_a"],
       "Integers" : [10, 15, 50, 30]}

df_pd = pd.DataFrame(df)
            
def string_int(x, y) :
    if x == 'string_a':
        return 1
    elif x == 'string_b':
        return 0
    elif y <= 45:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


df_pd['1_or_0'] = string_int(df_pd['Strings'], df_pd['Intergers'])
```

The first problem that I run into is the error

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

and when I try to implement any of the suggested methods I get more errors.

I think the problem is that the code tries to compare the entire list instead of element wise.

A better solution should be available but I don't see it.

Starting to learn python making rookie mistakes but I would like to better understand the issue.

I am aware that the issue has been raised by multiple people but I never quite got a solution that worked for me as far as was visible.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is to pass series to a function,  therefore you need to return a series (of booleans)

In many ways it is simpler to do conditional logic with `np.where()` In this case I have used cascading ones to implement your logic.

```
import numpy as np

df = { "Strings" : ["string_a", "string_b", "string_b", "string_a"],
       "Intergers" : [10, 15, 50, 30]}

df_pd = pd.DataFrame(df)
df_pd = df_pd.assign(**{"1_or_0":lambda dfa: np.where(dfa.Strings.eq("string_a"), 1, 
                                    np.where(dfa.Intergers.le(45),1,0))})
```

|  | Strings | Intergers | 1_or_0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | string_a | 10 | 1 |
| 1 | string_b | 15 | 1 |
| 2 | string_b | 50 | 0 |
| 3 | string_a | 30 | 1 |